# Add "New" label to post not older than 24 hours

Tags: posts, labels

I did not found many results when searching in Google and the items that I found did not help me very much.

How can I add a label "New" to posts that are not older than 24 hours?

Is there a function I can add in my functions.php I can use to manage this?

Comment: Sorry to tell you that requests for plugins are off topic here. Also: Can you detail on what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to display them differently or add some tag or something else?

Comment: I'm very sorry. Did not know that. I just want to add "(NEW)" after the title of a posts that is not older than 24 hours. My PHP skills are not that good but I'm very sure it is possible by adding something to my functions.php or something...

Comment: Please try our search. I _know_ that we have already solutions for that.

Comment: All you need to do is to compare the post date with the current time, if the difference is more than 24hrs, add your custom text, if not, return nothing

Comment: Ha, found it. :)

Comment: Darn it, I was just about to post an answer when the question was closed. Unlike you veterans, I still need the xp!! ;)